# How to Identify If the user reloads the web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Actual Task is to confirm the user when he closes the tab or window.
For that I wrote the following code,

```
 var validNavigation = false;

 function wireUpEvents() {

  var dont_confirm_leave = 0; 
   var leave_message = 'You sure you want to leave?'
  function goodbye(e) {
    if (!validNavigation) {
      if (dont_confirm_leave!==1) {
         if(!e) e = window.event;
        //e.cancelBubble is supported by IE - this will kill the bubbling process.
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = leave_message;
       //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          e.preventDefault();
        }
        //return works for Chrome and Safari
        return leave_message;
      }
    }
  }
  window.onbeforeunload=goodbye;

  // Attach the event keypress to exclude the F5 refresh
  $(document).bind('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 116){
      validNavigation = true;
    }
  });

  // Attach the event click for all links in the page
  $("a").bind("click", function() {
    validNavigation = true;
  });

  // Attach the event submit for all forms in the page
  $("form").bind("submit", function() {
    validNavigation = true;
  });

  // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
  $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function() {
    validNavigation = true;
  });

  // Attach the event click for all inputs in the page
  $("input[type='button']").bind("click", function() {
    validNavigation = true;
  });

}

// Wire up the events as soon as the DOM tree is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  wireUpEvents();
});
```

the problem here is it asks confirmation if the user reloads the web page.
So i need to bind the reload event.

Please help me...
Thanks in advance

Comment: If the page reload is done following user interaction inside the document, you can use any kind of flag/logic. If you want to handle all case as user pressing F5, there is no way as far as i know

Comment: There's no way for JavaScript to know where the user navigates *to*, i.e. whether it is "merely" a reload. BTW: There are other keys that do a reload/navigate than F5, Safari on Mac uses `⌘+R` and of course you can do it through the context menu or the application menu, through scripts, refresh headers, browser add-ons, and so on. Catching `F5` will lead you nowhere. To JavaScript a page re-load looks just like any other navigation - the dialog will have to pop up. On the other hand bugging the user if they navigate away is rude. Simple solution: Don't do it *unless* there are unsaved changes.

Comment: Tomalak : My task is to update the user's login status to false, when he close the web application. So by using my code when user reloads the page then status updated to false. I need to set false only when user close the window.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.unload`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) or `.on('unload', handler)`:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  // your code here
});
```